# The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path 'fp' is not rooted

Tags: c#, .net, file

I am doing Image uploader in Asp.net and I am  giving following code under my controls:

```
    string st;
    st = tt.PostedFile.FileName;
    Int32 a;
    a = st.LastIndexOf("\\");
    string fn;
    fn = st.Substring(a + 1);
    string fp;
    fp = Server.MapPath(" ");
    fp = fp + "\\";
    fp = fp + fn;
    tt.PostedFile.SaveAs("fp");
```

But during uploading or saving image the error message comes that The **SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path 'fp' is not rooted.** 
So Please help me what is the problem

Comment: Out of interest, why have you split code which could easily be expressed in 5 lines into 11? Why declare a variable and only assign it in the next line?

Comment: Also take a look at System.IO.Path for manipulations of filenames.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're using the string "fp" instead of the variable `fp`. Here's the fixed code, also made (IMO) more readable:

```
string filename = tt.PostedFile.FileName;
int lastSlash = filename.LastIndexOf("\\");
string trailingPath = filename.Substring(lastSlash + 1);
string fullPath = Server.MapPath(" ") + "\\" + trailingPath;
tt.PostedFile.SaveAs(fullPath);
```

You should also consider changing the penultimate line to:

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(" "), trailingPath);
```

You might also want to consider what would happen if the posted file used / instead of \ in the filename... such as if it's being posted from Linux. In fact, you could change the whole of the first three lines to:

```
string trailingPath = Path.GetFileName(tt.PostedFile.FileName));
```

Combining these, we'd get:

```
string trailingPath = Path.GetFileName(tt.PostedFile.FileName));
string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(" "), trailingPath);
tt.PostedFile.SaveAs(fullPath);
```

Much cleaner, IMO :)

Comment: Thanks sir now no error is there but when I debug images are not shown in Gridview.

Comment: Without knowing what you're doing, it's hard to help you. I suggest you ask another question with more information.

Comment: Sir I had gridview in design view and in that I have 2 coloum Name,class,image. So for image I have fileuploader in Edititemtemplate as well in fottertemplate. But sir when I upload any image there is no error but images are not shown, same problem while updating. I am giving in source of image (itemtemplate) this code - <img src = '<%# Eval("img") width="50" height="50" runat="server"/>
But after uploading the image it is saving in my website folder in my system. But why it is not shown in browser. Please tell me solution. Many people saying that this the problem of window or machine.config.

Comment: This isn't suitable for dealing with in comments. Ask a new question.

Comment: In short, I had kind of the same problem as @Narinder described, got an error saying something like cannot / not allowed to access this file. That is because for the website, you still need to use the relative path.

`SO: use the full path to upload, use or make a relative path and store that in your database or whatever.`

Comment: Check this too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039725/server-mappath-physical-path-given-virtual-path-expected

Comment: amazingly enough, i had the same exact problem (quoting my variable)

Answer (score 7):

Use **`Server.MapPath()`**:

```
fileUploader.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/")+"file.jpg");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save the uploaded file to the *value* of fp, just pass it in, don't put it in quotes:

```
tt.PostedFile.SaveAs(fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

When reading the title of the question, I was thinking that it looked like you had put quotation marks around the variable name. Not really believing that it was so, I opened the question to read it, but it really was so...

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. The problem is that you did not specify the path of the server that you want the file to be saved. And here is a probably simpler answer:

```
string fileName = tt.PostedFile.FileName;
string savePath = Server.MapPath("Path/Of/The/Folder/Comes/Here/") + fileName);
tt.PostedFile.SaveAs(savePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

We cannot use the "**SaveAs**" method to write directly to an FTP server.
Only local paths and UNC paths are supported for the above method.

To save it to FTP, please use the **FtpWebRequest** class.

You will get the full details to this in the same type of question answer in social.msdn.

Please go through the link.. and you will be able to solve the issue..

[enter link description here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c1bdbd6-4de0-410e-9f5a-baff80f23c9c/the-saveas-method-is-configured-to-require-a-rooted-path-and-the-path-is-not-rooted?forum=csharpgeneral)

--thanks for the answer by ***Jesse HouwingXPirit (MCC, Partner, MVP)***