# Server.MapPath - Physical path given, virtual path expected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using this line of code:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("E:\\ftproot\\sales"));
```

to locate files in a folder however I get the error message saying that

> "Physical Path given but virtual path
>   expected".

Am new enough to using System.IO in C# so I was wondering if it's possible to enter a physical path to do this?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

if you already know your folder is: **E:\ftproot\sales** then you do not need to use Server.MapPath, this last one is needed if you only have a relative virtual path like **~/folder/folder1** and you want to know the real path in the disk...

Comment: thanks for that, I wasn't aware. Do you have any suggestions so as to what I would use?

Comment: it depends, why do you have E:\\ftproot\\sales hard coded? if it's fixed and only that you just do GetFiles("E:\\ftproot\\sales")... I would anyway have that path in the web.config so no magic strings around and easier to change it and find it without rebuilds...

Answer (score 10):

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\ftproot\sales");
```