# Additional information: 'M:/uploads/' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to place uploaded files to our common drive which is accessible from the server. But it is giving `Additional information: 'M:/uploads/' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.`

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="DirPath" value="M:/uploads/"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Code

```
String fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
 String extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
 var directory = Server.MapPath(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirPath"]
                                    .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

How to access that path?

Comment: Seems pretty clear - `MapPath` requires a virtual path, while you're providing an absolute path - you don't need `MapPath`  in that case.

Comment: Answered here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039725/server-mappath-physical-path-given-virtual-path-expected

Answer (score 0):

As the exception clearly states you can't (in fact you don't *need* to) use `MapPath` for absolute paths.  If you want to support absolute paths in your config then just inspect the value to see if the path is absolute:

```
 string directory = @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirPath"]
                                         .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
 if(!(path.Contains(":") || path.Contains(@"\\") || path.Contains(@"//"))
    // convert virtual to physical path
    directory = Server.MapPath();
 else
```