# Error: Is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to save a word document to the following path, however, I cannot figure out why I keep getting the same error

```
using (StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/path/tofolder/" + filename)))
{
    myStream.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
}
```

I have also tried changing the path to

```
c:\inetpub\path\tofolder
c:/inetpub/path/tofolder/
```

as well as

```
~//path//tofolder//
```

Still I get the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing MapPath from your code, I think MapPath is used to locate the physical path to files in a virtual location. I'm currently on linux so I can't test this answer before giving it, but try something to the effect of:

```
using (StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter("~/path/tofolder/" + filename))
{
    myStream.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
}
```

I'm guessing this is similar to the question at --> [Server.MapPath - Physical path given, virtual path expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039725/server-mappath-physical-path-given-virtual-path-expected?rq=1)