# Get .ini file from IIS 7 asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I am trying to get some parameters from an .ini file that is inside of my project folder ( asp aplicattion).

I've been doing it like that:

```
const string rutaserver = "iniciativas/iniciativas/parametros/sapconf.ini"; 

const string rutaserver = "http:ffr.cl/iniciativas/iniciativas/parametros/sapconf.ini";
```

Whit no success.

What is the exact path? 
there is a way to get it from c# (function)?

Comment: [HttpServerUtility.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of my most voted answers so far :)

use this syntax in order to get on the server the full absolute physical path of a file for which you know the relative path, then you can use standard .NET `system.IO` classes to pen the file at the path returned by that command:

```
Server.MapPath("~/iniciativas/parametros/sapconf.ini");
```

Mind that the relative path above in the command might need some adjustments depending on how your website / app / virtual directory is configured..

See here: [Server.MapPath - Physical path given, virtual path expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039725/server-mappath-physical-path-given-virtual-path-expected/5039753#5039753)

Comment: Ive imported SYSTEM.IO and mark error Server.MapPath.