# Asp.net: - is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, virtual-path

I want to download an excel file format from my local PC, So I wrote my code as below

```
protected void btnDownloadExcelTemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string strFileFormat = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FormateFilePath"].ToString();
        string strFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strFileFormat + "/CMP_TEMPLATES.xlsx");
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "CMP_TEMPLATES.xlsx");
        response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        response.WriteFile(strFilePath);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {            
        throw;
    }
}
```

and `strFileFormat` is `<add key="FormateFilePath" value="D:/Name/CMP/CMP Excel Template"/>`

So while downloading I am getting error as

> 'D:/Name/CMP/CMP Excel Template/CMP_TEMPLATES.xlsx' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.

I dont know what path its expecting. Please suggest

Comment: `strFileFormat = "~/Name/CMP/CMP Excel Template/CMP_TEMPLATES.xlsx"` is enough i think. Try `response.WriteFile(strFileFormat );`

Comment: Duplicate of [Server MapPath - Physical given, virtual path expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039725/server-mappath-physical-path-given-virtual-path-expected)

Comment: @RishiKalal: that's what I tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server.MapPath - Physical path given, virtual path expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039725/server-mappath-physical-path-given-virtual-path-expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading the doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx .

`MapPath` generates a physical path based on a releative or virtual path, so it makes no sense to give it a physical path. You already have the physical path so you should be able to completely skip that step.

```
protected void btnDownloadExcelTemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string strFileFormat = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FormateFilePath"].ToString();
        string strFilePath = strFileFormat + "/CMP_TEMPLATES.xlsx";
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "CMP_TEMPLATES.xlsx");
        response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        response.WriteFile(strFilePath);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {            
        throw;
    }
}
```