# FileUpload does not upload file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I want to upload an image to file but there is an exception as ***"The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '../TempCharcoal/IMG_0153.JPG' is not rooted."***

Here is my simple code:

```
if (fuImage.HasFile)
  {
     fuImage.SaveAs("../TempCharcoal/IMG_0153.JPG");
  }
```

I want to upload it in CharcoalForm.aspx to TempCharcoal folder. You can see that they are in the same root but I don't know what is wrong.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206662/the-saveas-method-is-configured-to-require-a-rooted-path-and-the-path-fp-is-n

Comment: @SteveDanner it's not a duplicate, but could be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
if (fuImage.HasFile)
  {
     fuImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~/TempCharcoal/IMG_0153.JPG"));
  }
```

The file path that you have is a relative path (relative to whatever directory .. is). The [MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) method will return the physical file path that corresponds to that path.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
string myPath = @"~\TempCharcoal\IMG_0153.jpg";
fuImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(myPath));
```